# How can I set a JSP Attribute from another Sevlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a login and a register form in the same JSP, but I'd like to them to call two different servlet. The main functions are works, so you can log in or register, but if something happened, I'd like to change a ${message} attribute on the main page both from the Login and the Register servlet. How can I do it?

Login JSP page (login.jsp)

```
<form action="register" method="POST">
    INPUTS...
</form>
<form action="login" method="POST">
    INPUTS...
</form>
```

Login Servlet (LoginSV.java)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    //Happens when e-mail or password incorrect
    request.setAttribute("message", "Incorrect email/password.");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return;
}
```

Register Servlet (RegisterSV.java)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {       
    //Happens if user leaves a field empty
    request.setAttribute("message", "One or more field is epty.");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return;
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginSV</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.LoginSV</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterSV</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.RegisterSV</servlet-class>
</servlet> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginSV</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterSV</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have the forms in the login.jsp file, so the Login Servlet can change the attribute (so it works fine in case the login form calls it), but the Register can't, the ${message} variable isn't there in any form.

Comment: What is the error ? You are already setting `request.setAttribute("message", "One or more field is epty.");`, is it NOT dispalyed?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. It doesn't matter which servlet sets `message`, if it's set by anything, it'll be displayed. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: Yeah, the attribute isn't there.

Comment: Then you're either not hitting the servlet you think you are, or you're not displaying what you think you are.

Comment: The LoginSV does exactly the same things that the RegisterSV, but the login works and the register is not.

Comment: Then it should work just fine. Without any more details it's impossible to help. Make sure you're running the code you think you are, that "message" is spelled correctly in both places, and that the code path you think you're running is actually running.

Comment: I dont know what else could I show you to make it easier to help. I looking for solution since yesterday evening, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that duplicates the problem and put it on github/etc. All I can say is that if the servlet is being hit (which I assume you've verified?) and there are no other errors, it'll work. That it doesn't suggests an error in assumptions or code since this is about as basic as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved. There were a redirect script in the login.jsp what screwed the things up. Thanks everyone.